# Trigger border visibility on ListView GroupStyle

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a `ListView` sourced to a `CollectionViewSource` to enable grouping. All good. I have written my `ListView.GroupStyle` with a `ControlTemplate` which declares a header `TextBlock` & a `Border` around the `ItemsPresenter`. All good.

I now want to handle Visibility property of the `Border` to only make Visible when the group contains items of a certain type. I have tried to write a trigger but I understand that the `GroupItem` is dumb to the properties of the items so cannot simply set the trigger property to a boolean property on my item object? Is there a way to achieve this?

```
 <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                     <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate 
                            TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                     <Border x:Name="ScenarioGroupBorder" 
                                             Background="LightGray">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                             FontSize="14" 
                                                             FontWeight="Bold"
                                                            Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                             <ItemsPresenter/>
                                          </StackPanel>
                                      </Border>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                         <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                          <Trigger Property="?" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="{Binding 
                                                    ElementName=ScenarioGroupBorder}"
                                                    Property="Border.Visibility"
                                                    Value="Visible"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: I have a collection source of an ObservableCollection which is a public property on my view model. I'm using MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext` of a `GroupItem` has an `Items` property that contains all grouped items so you should be able to use a `DataTrigger` to trigger on a public property of an item in the group:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items[0].YourBoolProperty}" Value="True">
...
```